# securesocial redirect user on save

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, securesocial

I'm trying to make authentication work with securesocial plugin for Play! framework 2.2.
I'm implementing my own version of UserService.
When someone logs into my website for the first time using some identity (Facebook, Twitter or everything else) I want to redirect him to a Registration Page to collect more informations about him and to make him accept my Terms and Conditions.
How can I achieve this?

Thank you for your help.

## A.M.

Answer (score 0):

```
      def index = SecuredAction { implicit request =>
        // Check if user is logging in for the first-time... or other logic
        if(true){//If logic for redirection meets
        Redirect(routes.Application.step2)
        }else{
        println("Home")
        Ok(views.html.index(request.user))
        }
      }

  def step2 = SecuredAction { implicit request =>
        //Gather Other data... point to another form, your choice
        Ok(views.html.step2(request.user))
      }
```

I presume your files look like these..

**securesocial.conf**

```
    securesocial {
        onLoginGoTo=/
```

**routes.conf**

```
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index
GET /step2              controllers.AmazonController.step2 //Additional Route
```